# I keep getting an "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null at HTMLButtonElement.printResult"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I keep getting an uncaught type error at resultImg.setAttribute('src',"./img/"+movies+".jpg"). I have no idea what I am doing wrong. I think it has something to do with my strings, it's just I am not sure. I have been stuck on this for a few weeks, and I have not made any progress.

I have provided the section in which I think the error is hiding. I am hoping to get another pair of eyes on this to help me with my dilemma.
This is a snippet of the code from a school project, in which I have to make a form submission validator that leads to a 3 question quiz. It is supposed to be a BuzzFeed style quiz and show a "badge" (I have chosen to do Christmas movies) for the results of the quiz.
The form validates correct, there even is an anonymous button that works correctly, however, the only Issue I am having is trying to submit the quiz and get the image.

```
const quiz = () => {
    const Movie_INFO = [{
            name: 'Elf'
        },
        {
            name: 'Santa_Baby'
        },
        {
            name: 'Santa_Clause'
        },
        {
            name: 'Christmas_Vacation'
        },
        {
            name: 'Grinch'
        },

        {
            name: 'Kranks'
        },
        {
            name: 'Polar_Express'
        },
        {
            name: 'Mickey'
        }
    ]
    const Elf = ['a', 'a', 'a']
    const Santa_Baby = ['a', 'b', 'a']
    const Santa_Clause = ['a', 'a', 'b']
    const Christmas_Vacation = ['b', 'a', 'a']
    const Grinch = ['b', 'b', 'b']
    const Kranks = ['b', 'a', 'b']
    const Polar_Express = ['b', 'b', 'a']
    const Mickey = ['a', 'b', 'b']
    const movies = [Elf, Santa_Baby, Santa_Clause, Christmas_Vacation, Grinch, Kranks, Polar_Express, Mickey]
    let submission = document.getElementById('quiz_btn')
    let answers = new Array(3)
    let result = ''
    const getResult = () => {
        let radioInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]:checked')
        for (let i = 0; i < radioInputs.length; i++) {
            answers[i] = radioInputs[i].value
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < movies.length; i++) {
            if (JSON.stringify(movies[i]) === JSON.stringify(answers)) {
                result = Movie_INFO[i].name
            }
        }
        return result
    }
    const printResult = () =>{
        let movies = getResult()
       let resultBox = document.getElementById('result')
       let resultImg = document.getElementById('movies')
       resultImg.setAttribute('src',"./img/"+movies+".jpg")
       resultImg.setAttribute('alt',movies)
       console.log(resultImg)
        resultImg.nextElementSibling.textContent = "Congratulations! Your Movie is: " + movies
       resultBox.classList.remove('invisible')
       console.log(movies)
    }

    submission.addEventListener('click', printResult, false)
return
}
validateData(check)
quiz()
window.addEventListener('load', validateData, false)
```

Comment: The element with id of "movies" doesn't exist at the time you're trying to refer it.

Comment: It would be easier for us to help you if you provide the html code as well, but my guess is, as @Teemu said, the id doesn't exist at the time.
Are you waiting for the DOM to be loaded before executing your code?

Comment: Thanks @Teemu and I figured out what was wrong. For the HTML, I put "movie" instead of "movies"